# HttpResponse retona erro

Tags: java, android-studio

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
package carcleo.com.radiosingular.classes;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.loopj.android.http.HttpGet;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpResponse;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.HttpClient;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.HttpClients;

public class DownloadDados extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    JSONObject clientes = null;

    @Override
    public JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

        String URL = params[0];
        String linha = "";
        Boolean erro = false;

        try {

            HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();

            HttpGet requisicao = new HttpGet();

            requisicao.setURI(new URI(URL));

            HttpResponse resposta = client.execute(requisicao);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resposta.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");

            while ((linha = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(linha);
            }

            br.close();

            linha = sb.toString();


            Log.v("Será: ",linha);

            clientes = new JSONObject(linha);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("Erro: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return clientes;

    }

}
```

Quando chega nessa linha,

```
            HttpResponse resposta = client.execute(requisicao);
```

Obtenho o seguinte erro no **console** do `RUN` :

```
12/20 11:19:42: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t -p carcleo.com.radiosingular D:\Trabalhos\AndroidStudio\RadioSingular\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk 
Split APKs installed in 1 s 114 ms
$ adb shell am start -n "carcleo.com.radiosingular/carcleo.com.radiosingular.login" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Connected to process 6519 on device motorola-moto_g_play-0027377835
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/carcleo.com.radiosingular-1/lib/arm
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8916_32_LA.BR.1.2.9_RB1__release_AU (I750f7f2fa6)
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.09.00.03
    Build Date: 02/18/17 Sat
    Local Branch: 
    Remote Branch: quic/LA.BR.1.2.9_rb1.12
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/Adreno-ES20: <get_gpu_clk:229>: open failed: errno 13
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2341)
        at void android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at android.view.ViewGroup android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:607)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at void carcleo.com.radiosingular.teste.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (teste.java:25)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6687)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1140)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2631)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2743)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1490)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6165)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:888)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:778)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/carcleo.com.radiosingular-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/carcleo.com.radiosingular-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/carcleo.com.radiosingular-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/carcleo.com.radiosingular-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/carcleo.com.radiosingular-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/carcleo.com.radiosingular-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/carcleo.com.radiosingular-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/carcleo.com.radiosingular-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/carcleo.com.radiosingular-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/carcleo.com.radiosingular-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/carcleo.com.radiosingular-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/carcleo.com.radiosingular-1/split_lib_slice_9_
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2341)
        at void android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at android.view.ViewGroup android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:607)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at void carcleo.com.radiosingular.teste.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (teste.java:25)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6687)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1140)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2631)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2743)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1490)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6165)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:888)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:778)
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: carcleo.com.radiosingular, PID: 6519
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{carcleo.com.radiosingular/carcleo.com.radiosingular.teste}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2678)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1490)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.util.Log.println_native_inner(Native Method)
        at android.util.Log.println_native(Log.java:294)
        at android.util.Log.v(Log.java:306)
        at carcleo.com.radiosingular.classes.DownloadDados.doInBackground(DownloadDados.java:57)
        at carcleo.com.radiosingular.teste.onCreate(teste.java:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6687)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2631)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1490) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

Comment: O problema é que a variável `linha` esta nula aqui > `Log.v("Será: ",linha);` Segundo a mensagem de erro a `message` não pode ser vazia.

Comment: Não entendi seu comentário, o erro ocorre bem antes, na linha             HttpResponse resposta = client.execute(requisicao); Além disso, posso comentar ou até mesmo exclui essw Log.v que o erro continua.

Comment: Sim... A causa do primeiro erro é `ClassNotFoundException` que não encontrou a classe `android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener` nos caminhos....

Comment: Provavelmente está faltando coisas nesse pacote ai. E pelo que eu ví essa Classe está obsoleta.

Comment: então, achei, e é o mesmo erro de uma outa pergunta que fiz, precisa colocar             StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
para o acesso a intenet funcionar. Será que essas bibliotecas estão depreciadas? Existe código mais novo para isso?

Comment: a outra pergunta é https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/352332/problemas-com-strictmode-threadpolicy

Comment: Eu nunca usei essas bibliotecas. Para fazer conexões em web service eu uso, geralmente, o `Volley`.