# problemas com StrictMode.ThreadPolicy

Tags: java, android-studio

Olá, tenho o link abaixo

http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/ws/clientest.php

que me entrega uma string `json` do tipo

```
{
  "clientes":[
     {
       "idClientesT":"1",
       "tipo":"s",
       "nome":"Carlos"},
     {
       "idClientesT":"2",
       "tipo":"s",
       "nome":"Rogério"
     }
  ]
}
```

Então, no `AndroidStudio`, manipulo ela com a `Classe` abaixo:

```
package carcleo.com.radiosingular;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import carcleo.com.radiosingular.classes.Clientes;
import carcleo.com.radiosingular.classes.JsonClass;

public class form extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.form);
    }

    public void listaClientes (View View) {

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9){
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        String url = "http://hotplateprensas.com.br/ws/clientest.php";
        JsonClass json = new JsonClass();
        ArrayList<Clientes> clientesLista = json.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        Log.v("Cliente 2", clientesLista.get(1).getNome());

    }

}
```

Esse `código` funciona normalmente. Porém, é preciso colocar o trecho de código abaixo;

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9){
   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
   StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

Senão, a conexão com a internet NÃO é estabelecida.

No entanto, eu já adicionei a permissão de acesso à INTERNET no `AndroidManifest`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="carcleo.com.radiosingular">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".form" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Mas não adianta.

Se eu retirar esse bloco de código

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9){
   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
   StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

A conexão com a `INTERNET` não acontece.

O problema é que, se eu trabalhar desse jeito, quantas vezes forem as que eu precisar acessar à `INTERNET` será o mesmo número de vezes que terei que fazer uso desse trecho de código.

Será que não existe um arquivo de configuração geral para isso no `AndroidStudio`?

Segue a `classe` *JsonClass*:

```
package carcleo.com.radiosingular.classes;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpEntity;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpResponse;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.ClientProtocolException;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.methods.HttpPost;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class JsonClass {

    InputStream input = null;
    JSONObject jObect = null;
    String json = "";

    //Recebe sua url
    public ArrayList<Clientes> getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        //HTTP request
        try {
            // default HttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            input = httpEntity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            input.close();

            json = sb.toString();//

            // Transforma a String de resposta em um JSonObject
            jObect = new JSONObject(json);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // retorna o objeto
        return Clientes(jObect);

    }

    private ArrayList<Clientes> Clientes (JSONObject jObect) {
       // Cria o Array List de Clientes
        ArrayList<Clientes> aCli = null;

        try {

            aCli = new ArrayList<>();
            //Pega o primeiro índice do Array de Objetos, no caso, o array Clientes
            JSONArray clientesLista = jObect.getJSONArray("clientes"); // aqui você faz o resgate da lista

            // Transforma a JSONArray de resposta em um Array de objjeo da Classe Clientes
            for (int i = 0; i < clientesLista.length(); i++) {
                //Pega cada íncide do array e atribui a uma variável
                JSONObject jSobj = clientesLista.getJSONObject(i);
                //Indetifica os campos do objeto
                int id =  Integer.parseInt(jSobj.getString("idClientesT"));
                //int id =  jSobj.getInt("idClientesT");
                String tipo = jSobj.getString("tipo");
                String nome = jSobj.getString("nome");
               //popula o objeto da classe de clientes
                Clientes cliente = new Clientes(id, tipo, nome);
                //Adiciona o objeto de Classe criado ào Array de Clientes
                aCli.add(cliente);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Erro no parsing doo objeto " + e.toString());
        }
        //Retorno o array de Clientes.
        return aCli;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

O que acontece é que seu `JsonClass` tenta acessar a rede (uma operação bloqueante) na main thread do Android, o que não é permitido.

Você pode ler mais um pouco sobre o assunto [neste link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads), mas pra resumir: A thread principal do Android é responsável por atualizar as views.

Fazer tarefas bloqueantes como acessar a rede ou o banco de dados nesta thread faz com que a view trave, dando aquele impressão de *lag* no aplicativo.

O link acima, inclusive, dá uma alternativa para solucionar este problema: fazer este tipo de tarefas dentro de [AsyncTasks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask).

---

Eu, particularmente prefiro delegar todo esse trabalho a bibliotecas como o [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Fazer o que você quer com esta lib é bem trivial:

[Depois de adicionar as dependências](https://square.github.io/retrofit/), defina o contrato em uma interface:

```
public interface HotPlateService {
  @GET("clientest.php")
  Call<List<Clientes>> listClientes();
}
```

Inicia a instância do serviço:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/ws/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();

HotPlateService service = retrofit.create(HotPlateService.class);
```

E para consumir o serviço de forma não bloqueante, basta chamar:

```
service.listClientes().enqueue(new Callback<List<Clientes>>() {
  @Override public void onResponse(Call<List<Clientes>> call, Response<List<Clientes>> response) {

  }

  @Override public void onFailure(Call<List<Clientes>> call, Throwable t) {

  }
});
```

Agora, dentro do callback `onResponse` você já tem a resposta do webservice parseada e pronta pra usar.

Comment: Mas, me diz uma coisa\. O que é melhor? A) Fazer uma classe comum e estender AsyncTask, B) usar o Retrofit ou 3) Usar Volley?

Comment: V/Errado:: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $